# JSON type error cannot use 'in' operator

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, each

im new to jquery and i have been struggling with a type error for the past hour or so. im using a .get ajax method to call a Codeigniter controller and then return some information.

here is the controller:

```
public function update_rates($dep_to_save,$dep_to_edit,$serial,$id_people){

    $rows=explode('&',$serial);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $id_value=explode('=',$row);
        $this->load->model('employee_master_model');


        $this->employee_master_model->save_rates($dep_to_save,$id_value[0],$id_value[1],$id_people);
    }

    print_r(json_encode($this->employee_master_model->get_rates($dep_to_edit,$id_people)));

}
```

and here is my script that is doing the ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){

    var to_save = $('#dep_select option:selected').text();
    $('#dep_select').mouseenter(function(){
     to_save = $('#dep_select option:selected').attr('id');
    });

   $('#dep_select').change(function(){
    var to_edit = $('#dep_select option:selected').attr('id');
   var serial= $('#values').serialize();

    $.get('<?php echo base_url("index.php/company/ajax/update_rates/'+to_save+'/'+to_edit+'/'+serial+'/$id_people") ?>',function(data){
        console.log(data);

        $.each(data,function(index,value){
            console.log(value);
        });

    });

   });

});


</script>
```

i have the .each function near the end to iterate through the different json values but i am getting a type error. the jquery documentation for .each() stated explicitly that it could be used on both objects and arrays so im pretty confused. any help as to why im getting this  error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `$.get()` towards the end of the code is mixing PHP and JS, which is literally impossible to execute properly. Remember that everything INSIDE `<?php ... ?>` is considered PHP code,s o you're trying to use a JS concatenation operation to stuff JS variables into PHP code. Again, this is impossible.

Comment: Are you sure `data` is an object, and not just the JSON string? `$.get()` won't necessarily guess correctly. What does the `console.log()` print? And what does `console.log(typeof(data));` print?

Comment: @MarcB actually that's PHP printing out the URL that `$.get()` will be calling. Awkward, but not unusual in CodeIgniter and other frameworks.

Comment: @PaulRoub: ah yeah, I see the `" ...'...'..."` construct now. Man but embedding languages 3 or 4 deep gives me a headache, especially when you've got A generating B which generates A... Obviously gives the syntax highlighter a headache as well, since it's miscoloring the `to_save` and other vars.

Comment: [{"value":"0"},{"value":"0"},{"value":"0"},{"value":"0"}] and you are right Paul Roub , its not an object its a string.

Comment: Then add a `"json"` parameter (as the last parameter to `$.get()`), or call [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), to be sure the result is interpreted and converted.

Comment: thanks, paul. using .getjson worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **$.get('/index.php/company/ajax/update_rates/'+to_save+'/**.....  in script 
and just  **echo**(json_encode($this->employee_master_mod .....
instead of  **print_r**(json_encode($this->employee_master_mod.....  in your controller

Answer (score 0):

**Two things to be corrected:**

1) As said by @Marc B and suggested by @jerryManyanda, you have to use **text URL** and not **URL echoed by PHP**.

2) Also you have to declare **`header('Content-Type:')`** before returning **`json_encode()`**  back to your AJAX call.
The Content-type header is just used as info for your application. The browser doesn't care what it is. The browser just returns you the data from the AJAX call. If you want to parse it as JSON, you need to do that on your own.

The header is there so your app can detect what data was returned and how it should handle it. You need to look at the header, and if it's application/json then parse it as JSON.

Hence modify your **controller code** as below:

```
public function update_rates($dep_to_save,$dep_to_edit,$serial,$id_people)
{
   $rows=explode('&',$serial);
   foreach($rows as $row)
   {
      $id_value=explode('=',$row);
      $this->load->model('employee_master_model');

      $this->employee_master_model->save_rates($dep_to_save,$id_value[0],$id_value[1],$id_people);
   }

   header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode($this->employee_master_model->get_rates($dep_to_edit,$id_people));
}
```